# Calling a method when user leaves view controller inside container View

Tags: swift3, uicontainerview, peripherals

I am attempting to disconnect from a peripheral when ever a user leaves the current view controller. This would normally be easy by using prepare for segue in the following fashion:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    manager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
}
```

This doesnt work, however; because the view controller is inside a container view. Does anybody know how to call this method when ever the container view is change from this view controller to a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put it in `func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)` or `func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool)`.  Both will get called when the user navigates away from the view controller for any reason.